# Can I use 'macaronic' to descibe light verses involving three languages?

Tags: vocabulary

Possible *macaronic* confusion:

> 1. 'Of or involving a mixture **of two or more** languages.' ([American Heritage](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=macaronic&submit.x=53&submit.y=23))
> 2. 'characterized by a mixture **of two** languages' ([Merriam-Webster](http://i.word.com/idictionary/macaronic))

Since in an essay I'm writing I want to use the word 'macaronic' to descibe light verses involving three languages, I have the fear of not being understood because above dictionaries don't read the same definitions.

1. Can I use, contrary to what Merriam-Webster reads, 'macaronic' to descibe light verses involving three languages?
2. If not, can you suggest me an alternative adjective meaning 'light verses involving three languages'?

I ask because I want to avoid confusion in reader's brains.

Comment: No, 'macaronic' becomes 'linguinic' when three languages are involved, just as it becomes 'ditalinic' when two languages are involved, 'quadrefioric' with four, and 'pennic' with five. This is exclusive of cheese, you understand.

Comment: It's **describe** in your title. As for using macaronic in your essay, if I were a reader I would need to guess its meaning, here I didn't because you provided the definition. Perhaps the first time you use the word, write its definition alongside it, it's an act of courtesy to the reader. For such technical terms, you risk sounding presumptuous, as the average person would not know its meaning. Unless of course you are writing an academic paper, if that's the case, Andrew Leach's advice to add a footnote, sounds the best.

Answer (score 3):

Add a footnote to the first use of the word, explaining what you mean by it. And perhaps quoting the MW definition as well. You have found a dictionary which defines the word in a way which suits your use: use it.

Although the term *macaronic* is certainly known among those who have studied the form, they may not be familiar with using it for thee languages. And there may be other readers of your essay who would be grateful for a definition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the audience are likely to be familiar with the term, I'd say fine, but be aware that the term has a derogatory nuance and so is best used only when the works mix language for comedic or satirical effect (I'm guessing they do since you said "light verses").

If the audience wasn't likely to be familiar with the term, I'd favour *trilingual*.

On the other hand, there's no need to never send your readers to a dictionary, so if *macaronic* really expresses something that *trilingual* doesn't (in particular, if it uses puns that works across the different languages involved), then certainly do use it.

Comment: Macaronic carols (eg *In dulci jubilo*) don't mix Latin with the indigenous language for comedy or satire.

Comment: @AndrewLeach true, though the idea that the vernacular form was there for the less educated is where the idea of the term being less than complimentary comes from, I understand.